# URL rewrite replace + with %20

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, iis-7.5

This worked fine in IIS 6. Now using IIS 7.5 and cannot figure the problem out. Trying to get a bespoke app working, it's a file manager. When attempting to access files with spaces in the files names IIS encodes the URL as `files/This+is+a+filename.doc` and throws a cannot find file. I need it to encode the URL as `files/This%20is%20a%20filename.doc`.

Been looking at URL rewrite but cannot get my head around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is regex even an option? `Request.QueryString["filename"].Replace("+","%20")`, no? Or [Server.URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The app calls a class, outputFile() of which I have no access to, as it is within a DLL, so I don't believe it to be that simple?

Comment: FYI: `+ to space` form is [Query string-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not [URI-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Note that `+` *is still valid* un-encoded in a URI, but it maps to `+` (%2B) and not `space` (%20). Best is to fix the generator/code to *use a proper URI escape function*. (I assume it [bespoke] is handing off a URI to IIS instead of treating that as a query string and handling the fetch internally -- perhaps this changed?)

Comment: Also trying to move this over to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), still love ya' :-) It may or may not apply, in particular where the URL rewrite is intended to be done (inside IIS I presume?), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can change url encoding. No need for regular expressions.